# Access Raspberry Pi behind a NAT firewall through Internet

Tags: networking, nextcloud, nextcloudpi

I have been developing projects with Raspberry Pi 4. For the current project I am running a NextCloudPi server on it. I am able to access the server using my Internal IP. I want to access it using a public domain name or in other words through open Internet. My ISP does not allow port forwarding and static IP.

I tried Zerotier, which creates a VPN and I can access the CloudServer through the static IP assigned under VPN but the transfer speeds are really slow. Another issue is that I need to install it on all the devices through which I am going to access the CloudServer and ofcourse on the RPi4 itself.

Is there any other option that you guys probably have to access RPi4(Basically IOT devices) through Internet? Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

`ip addr` output

`1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000 link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00 inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever inet6 ::1/128 scope host valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever`

`2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000 link/ether dc:a6:32:6a:82:e4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff inet 192.168.1.35/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute eth0 valid_lft 85963sec preferred_lft 75163sec inet6 fe80::f6e0:36ba:532f:10e9/64 scope link valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever`

`3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000 link/ether dc:a6:32:6a:82:e5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff`

Comment: have you tried port forwarding on your internet router? Not sure how an ISP can stop you from port forwarding ... I guess your ISP could stop incoming connections of course - but they can't stop port forwarding

Comment: Maybe [Dataplicity](https://www.dataplicity.com/)? The Pi connects to the server, not the other way around so it works behind firewalls.

Comment: @JaromandaX , I tried port forwarding on my router but could not find any setting like that. The router is DBC XPON and has really bad web interface and it has a fiber connection.
Really not sure how to port forward my router so was searching for other way around.

Comment: @Unsigned_Arduino I tried Dataplicity using the instructions provided oon their website. I am able to acces the default Dataplicity server nginx but not able to access NextCloudPi's apache server. Not sure why, any inputs?

Comment: Is it running in port 80, and nothing else is using it?

Comment: Now the real issue has come to light ... *Really not sure how to port forward my router* is very different to your claim that *ISP does not allow port forwarding*

Comment: "*My ISP does not allow port forwarding and static IP.*" - does he give you a global IPv6 address? Most provider do it out of the box nowadays. If not, you should consider to change the provider. Can you please [edit](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/posts/120247/edit) your question and add the output of this command to it: `ip addr`.

Comment: Is your RasPi direct connected to the internet router to the provider?

Comment: @Unsigned_Arduino Yes I checked using `netstat -nltp`. I am able to access the NextcloudPi web interface through local IP on port 80.

Comment: Did you enable the worm hole? There is a switch to enable it on on the device terminal page.

Comment: @JaromandaX , really sorry for my ignorance. I have searched the router's web Interface for port forwarding but there is no option for the same. I contacted my ISP regarding port forwarding and they simply told me 'They can not provide static IP' . Not sure how port forwarding and static IP is related. The ISP uses NAT and as far as I am aware, I won't be able to port forward. Check  [link](https://broadbandforum.co/t/207465/#post-1503556) .

Comment: @Ingo Yes my RPi4 is connected via lan to the router.

Comment: @Unsigned_Arduino Yes I turned on the wormhole but met with `Too many redirects` error while trying to visit the web address given on dataplicity webpage.

Comment: "*my RPi4 is connected via lan to the router*" - that's good. So you should get a global ipv6 address if your provider supports it. But on **eth0** you have only a link-local address fe80::f6e0:36ba:532f:10e9/64. That's not good. Is there a way to enable ipv6 support on your internet router?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have finally resolved the issue. I have used `ngork` to create virtual tunnel. I tried to use `ngork` earlier but was unable as I was running the service on *port 80*. When I ran the `nrogk` http service on *port 443*, I was able to access the NextCloud server using the domain name shown on the ssh terminal. NextCloud uses *port 80 for http* and *443 for https*. I am really not sure why I was not able to access the NextCloud on *port 80*. This may help if someone is stuck in the similar problem. The problem with `ngork` is, once the raspberry pi is restarted you will have to restart the `ngork` service as well and of course the domain address will also be changed. Though my use case don't have any problem with it.

Comment: Yes. Ngrok creates an ephemeral public endpoints for the tcp or http tunnels created.  It is temporary and changes every time your device reboots.  SocketXP always creates a permanent public endpoints for your web service and it never changes.  Also SocketXP can be run as a Linux systemd daemon in the background and automatically starts on reboot.

Answer (score 2):

**Full disclosure: I am the founder of SocketXP.

If you want to remotely access your Raspberry Pi behind NAT firewall from anywhere, you can use [SocketXP IoT Remote Access solution](https://www.socketxp.com/iot-remote-access).  You can SSH,VNC or RDP into your Raspberry Pi remotely over the internet.  SocketXP also provides a public web-url to remotely access the web service running in your private Raspberry Pi device.  It is free to use.

### SocketXP IoT Remote Access Solution

Follow the instructions below to setup remote access to your Raspberry Pi via SSH.

#### Step#1: Download and Install:SocketXP IoT Agent

[Download and install](https://www.socketxp.com/download) SocketXP IoT agent on your IoT or Raspberry Pi device.

#### Step#2: Login

[Sign up here](https://portal.socketxp.com/#/login) to get your AuthToken.  SocketXP has a free plan to try without any strings attached.

Get your authtoken and register your device using the following command:

```
$ socketxp login <your-authtoken-goes-here>
```

#### Step#3: Connect and Access

Next connect your Raspberry Pi or IoT Device to SocketXP Cloud Gateway.

```
$ socketxp connect tcp://127.0.0.1:22

Connected to SocketXP Cloud Gateway.
Access the TCP service securely using the SocketXP agent in IoT Slave Mode.
```

Now go to [SocketXP web portal](https://portal.socketxp.com/#/devices), go to the devices section, click the terminal icon next to your device, use your SSH login password to SSH into your device.

#### Public Web URL for any web service

For example, to remotely access a web service (like NextCloudPi) running on your localhost network (say, port 8080) over the internet, execute the below command. The command creates a secure HTTP tunnel to your localhost web service.

```
$ socketxp connect http://localhost:8080

Connected to SocketXP Cloud Gateway.
Public URL -> https://test-user-a29dfe42e3.socketxp.com
```

After you have successfully created the HTTP tunnel, use the public URL provided by SocketXP ( https://test-user-a29dfe42e3.socketxp.com ) to access your localhost web service (like NextCloudPi) from anywhere in the world.

You can also SSH connect to your Raspberry Pi using PuTTY or Filezilla as explained below.

#### Step #4: SSH access to Raspberry Pi using PuTTY or Filezilla

Download and install SocketXP agent on your laptop or PC(windows/mac/linux).

```
$ socketxp.exe connect tcp://localhost:3000 --iot-slave --peer-device-id <device-id> --peer-device-port 22 --authtoken <auth token>

Listening for TCP connections at:
Local URL -> tcp://localhost:3000
Accessing the IoT device from your laptop
```

Now open up PuTTY and connect to "localhost" and port "3000".  When prompted provide your SSH login/password.  You'll be placed in your Raspberry Pi Shell Prompt.

You can find more instructions on [how to setup remote access to your Raspberry Pi behind NAT router or Firewall over the internet](https://www.socketxp.com/remote-access-raspberry-pi) using SocketXP here.

Comment: Looks interesting. Will give it a try.